# Input not triggering if statements

Tags: python, input

I have problem with using my input, when i start program it asks me for input but no matter what that input is it just asks for input again and ignores if statements. I want my input to trigger function or ask for next input and then trigger function.

```
while True:
    f = input("Choose function (BasePosition; HalfUp; Forward; TurnLeft; TurnRight):")
    if f == "baseposition" or "BasePosition":
        BasePosition()
    elif f == "halfup" or "HalfUp":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        HalfUp(t)
    elif f == "forward" or "Forward":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        Forward(t)
    elif f == "turnleft" or "TurnLeft":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        TurnLeft(t)
    elif f == "turnright" or "TurnRight":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        TurnRight(t)
    else:
        print("I don't think so")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python evaluates both sides of the `if` condition seperately, and non-empty strings are Truthy, ie. they evaluate to True. Therefore your first condition always evaluates to True. For example

```
if "randomstring":
    # This will always be True

if 5==6 or 'randomstring':
    # Also True
```

So change your if conditions.

```
while True:
    f = input("Choose function (BasePosition; HalfUp; Forward; TurnLeft; TurnRight):")
    if f == "baseposition" or f=="BasePosition":
        BasePosition()
    elif f == "halfup" or f=="HalfUp":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        HalfUp(t)
    elif f == "forward" or f=="Forward":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        Forward(t)
    elif f == "turnleft" or f=="TurnLeft":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        TurnLeft(t)
    elif f == "turnright" or f=="TurnRight":
        t = int(input("Choose time:"))
        TurnRight(t)
    else:
        print("I don't think so")
```

Also just for fun I wanted to see if I could clean up your code to be a bit more elegant. This way you don't need a million if statements and its easier to expand.

```
function_map = {
    'baseposition': BasePosition,
    'halfup': HalfUp,
    'forward': Forward,
    'turnleft': TurnLeft,
    'turnright': TurnRight
}


while True:
    f = input("Choose function (BasePosition; HalfUp; Forward; TurnLeft; TurnRight):").lower()

    if hasattr(function_map, f):
        if f == baseposition:
            function_map[f]()
        else:
            try:
                t = int(input("Choose time:"))
                function_map[f](t)
            except ValueError:
                print("Value must be numeric")
    else:
        print("I don't think so")
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: added an edit maybe try to understand it to improve your coding.

Answer (score -1):

use break statement to exit out of the loop

```
f = input("Choose function (BasePosition; HalfUp; Forward; TurnLeft; 
     TurnRight):")
if f.lower() == "baseposition":  ### this was the problem
    BasePosition()
elif f == "halfup" or "HalfUp":
    t = int(input("Choose time:"))
    HalfUp(t)
    break

elif f == "forward" or "Forward":
    t = int(input("Choose time:"))
    Forward(t)
    break
elif f == "turnleft" or "TurnLeft":
    t = int(input("Choose time:"))
    TurnLeft(t)
    break
elif f == "turnright" or "TurnRight":
    t = int(input("Choose time:"))
    TurnRight(t)
    break
else:
    print("I don't think so")
    break
```

Comment: you can also use    f.lower() == "turnright" . that way  it will have less code

Comment: The if conditions need to be fixed aswell, they will always evaluate true

Comment: can you share the hole code,  there might be a problem with BasePosition() function used

Comment: I don't ever want to exit that loop, i just want it to execute function and ask again but I don't know what's the problem with my if statement. Rest of the code is fine because i checked those functions using normal loop without input, those functions are just commands for my hexapod robot

Comment: type(f == "baseposition" or "BasePosition") is giving str which  should be giving an boolean.

Comment: and that str is 'BasePosition'  which is coming from god knows where

Comment: @OmKhade Please read my answer to see why your answer is still very wrong...